# how to attach pen drive, and external HDD in ubuntu?

Tags: command-line

Could you please provide commands to:

- attach pen drive in Ubuntu system
- unmount command
- attach external HDD using mount command

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

1. Use `blkid` to view the list of disks and partitions. **Note which one is your pendrive, example: sdc3**
2. Create a folder where to mount sdc3 : `mkdir /path/to/myfolder`
3. Finally attach it (=mount it) `mount /dev/sdc3 /path/yo/myfolder`

---

To "eject" 
`umount /dev/sdc3` or `umount /path/to/myfolder`

Answer (score 0):

There is enough information for you here:

- Mount - http://linux.die.net/man/8/mount
- Umount - http://linux.die.net/man/8/umount

Comment: [lsblk](http://manpages.courier-mta.org/htmlman8/lsblk.8.html) and [fdisk -l](http://linux.die.net/man/8/fdisk) are useful to get information on the blocks/devices you potentially can mount

Answer (score 0):

1. Use `lsblk` to see attached drives
2. Mount with `sudo mount /dev/sdb1 /dev/mnt` (replace `sdb1` with output of previous command)
3. Explore with `ls /dev/mnt` or `nautilus /dev/mnt`
4. Unmount with `sudo umount /dev/mnt`